# Hadoop | Archlinux | DFS: cannot launch start-dfs.sh

Tags: hadoop, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have issue with **dfs** in **hadoop**. Does somebody know how to solve my problem?

```
[hduser@evghost ~]$ start-dfs.sh 
Starting namenodes on [evghost]
Error: Please specify one of --hosts or --hostnames options and not both.
evghost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/lib/hadoop-2.7.1/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-evghost.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
Error: Please specify one of --hosts or --hostnames options and not both.
```

As you can see here is something with **hosts** and **hostname.** I don't know what to do here about 2 days... I didn't find any solution of this problem in internet, help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's issue with DNS server. If you have a hostname not like 'localhost' you'll not to be able to deploy a pseudo mode for dfs because DNS won't give you ip address from your request domain name. Here i had a hostname **evghost**, lets look:

```
[main@evghost ~]$ host evghost
Host evghost not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

DNS didn't get answer to you. Noway to deal with it, but you can set up your own dns server in your PC. Much pain, but i think it can works.

Solution is to post

> localhost

in **/etc/hostname** and **NOT** another! 
I spend 2 days to understand that, hate this technology and like it together.